# Need close GTK+ window after execute the function

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am programming on linux program and I am trying to prepare program with GTK+3, but I don't know how close program automatically after execute the function without kill that execute.

the step that i want in my program is:

1. open gtk window and this window there is button (open Xreader).
2. press button, it tells system to execute *xreader program*.
3. close gtk window automatically without needing to close *xreader* .

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

static void 
open_app(GtkWidget *Widget, gpointer data){

system("xreader");
gtk_main_quit();

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     GtkWidget *window;
     GtkWidget *button1;
     
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
/*make window */
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  /*give name to the window*/
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "launcher");
  /*make size of window*/
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 700, 700);
  /*open the window in the meddal*/
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open Xreader");
  
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button1);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  g_signal_connect(button1,"clicked",G_CALLBACK(open_app), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

everytime trying to execute my program and press the button (open Xreader) gtk not close till close *xreader* .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `system` here, because according to its documentation, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html

> system() returns after the command has been completed.

Since you are using gtk, don't forget library functions provided by `glib`. It has a bunch of functions related to process and thread handling. For example, you can use `GSubprocess` class from `glib`, [g_subprocess_new](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/ctor.Subprocess.newv.html).

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>

static void open_app(GtkWidget *Widget, gpointer data) {
  g_subprocess_new(G_SUBPROCESS_FLAGS_NONE, NULL, "xreader", NULL);
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button1;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  /*make window */
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  /*give name to the window*/
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "launcher");
  /*make size of window*/
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 700, 700);
  /*open the window in the meddal*/
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

  button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open Xreader");

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button1);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  g_signal_connect(button1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(open_app), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works now.